# Test subscribe functionality of paypal

Tags: php, paypal

I've created the paypal subscribe button and after going through the docs I'm having a real hard time understanding how can I test the button and check how feedback is received on my website. When I click the button I'm asked to login into paypal but when I do it says the account is the same as the seller. So, trying to search for a way to test it I found I have two *sandbox* accounts, as follows:

- email-buyer@gmail.com
- email-facilitator@gmail.com

Both from the US although I'm **EU**. When I tried to log in with those after clicking the button it always failed the password/account check. Can someone help me understand the whole mechanism and how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make sure you have 1 sandbox seller account (which it sounds like you've got working already) and 1 sandbox buyer account.  Then you'll login with the buyer account, and make sure it's running on the sandbox.paypal.com server, of course.

As long as your login credentials for that sandbox buyer account are correct and you're actually logging into sandbox.paypal.com then you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: I don't remember choosing any password for the sandbox account. How can I check this and change if needed? Is there a difference if I'm in EU and the sandbox account is US?